# Connecting to multiple Websockets

Tags: python, websocket

How can i connect to multiple websockets in a loop using websocket_client module in python. I tried with to connect under a loop it just connect first of them.

Comment: Can you share some code? It is easier to offer answers if we can see what you have already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If are you using websocket_client you can use threading for connecting multiple websockets at a time.